# MVC Dropdownlist with unselectable default item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple dropdown list that looks like this:

> Please Select, Male, Female

The "Please Select" is selected by default (on create), but the user must select a value or the validation should fail.

What can I do to achieve this validation on the client-side? [Required] in the model does not seem to work.

Comment: What is the `value` attribute of the "Please Select" option? It *should* be an empty string. That's enough to trigger the `Required` validation to fire if it's selected, since an empty string does not satisfy the constraint.

Comment: What is the property your binding to? - assuming its `[Required] string Gender { get; set; }`, then `@Html.DropwDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new SelectList( new string[] { "Male", "Female" }), "Please select") @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender)` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would work if you check the value in the editor.
Like:

```
return (!content.Equals("Please Select");
```

Answer (score 0):

But couldn't you make the dropdown list have 2 options: `Male` and `Female` and the default is just a set text, since the default is a text and not a `SelectedIndex` you could use that to validate. you would be able to see that it is set `if (dropdownlist.SelectedIndex != -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

For validation, *JavaScript* or *jQuery* will be your friend.  Especially for validation, you can do it a couple of ways.  The approach I would take would be:

```
$('#drpExample').on('change', function () {
     var content = $(this).val();
     if(content === 'default') {
         // Default Selection, Display Error.
     }
});
```

*jQuery* really simplifies this quite a bit, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `RegularExpression` attribute, this way you will have **validation** on both **client** and **server** side.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\b(Male|Female)", ErrorMessage = "Please Select, Male, Female")]
public string Gender{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class yourentity
{
     public SelectList GenderList { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public int gender { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult youraction()
{
    yourentity a = new yourentity();
    a.GenderList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value ="2"},
    });
    return View(a);
}
```

In your view

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m=>m.gender,m.GenderList ,"Select Gender")
@Html.ValidationMessagefor(m=>m.gender)
```